# Uploading multiple file with swagger api documentation and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen

I want to upload a list of files using swagger api and I can not find a way in which I get the endpoint generated having a list of MultipartFile. Could you please help me? I also searched in the swagger documentation without any luck. For now I have the following swagger config:

```
    x-swagger-router-controller: attachments
    post:
      operationId: saveFiles
      summary: saves the uploaded files
      tags:
        - files
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: files
          in: formData
          type: array
          items:
            type: file
          description: Files to be uploaded
          required: true
        - name: type
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          description: File types
          in: path
          required: true
      responses:
        201:
          description: Saved files
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CreatedFilesResponse'
        415:
          description: Unsupported media type
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
```

this code generates the following spring endpoint

```
    public ResponseEntity<CreatedAttachmentsResponse> createFile(List<File> list, List<String> list1) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: File arrays are not supported in OpenAPI 2.0. You need OpenAPI 3.0 to upload multiple files, see https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/#multiple